# Infinite loop excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

This would appear to be a simple problem yet no matter what I change or edit, I can't seem to fix this issue in a logical way.

What I am trying to do is loop through every cell in the range, comparing the contents of the current cell in the loop to the cell above it. If these two cell values are not the same, then I insert 2 new rows.

However, instead of 2 new, blank rows being inserted, it takes the contents of the row at `rangeCell` and inserts that instead. Thus, it gets stuck in an infinite loop because the cell above the one we are checking always equals the current cell value. Why is this happening?

Here is the code:

```
For Each rep In repNames()

    If rep <> vbNullString Then

    Worksheets(rep).Activate
    Set repComboRange = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

        For Each rangeCell In repComboRange

            If rangeCell.Value <> rangeCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value And rangeCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value <> vbNullString Then

            rangeCell.EntireRow.Insert
            rangeCell.EntireRow.Insert

            End If

        Next rangeCell

    Else: Exit For

    End If


Next rep
```

The particular problem is at this line:

```
            rangeCell.EntireRow.Insert
            rangeCell.EntireRow.Insert
```

This is what should happen: https://gyazo.com/c7f2bf238837fe2e3bca31a4505f6b4e

However, this is what is happening:https://gyazo.com/28f8cc028887df565b542cdd7cb04cf2

Any help is hugely appreciated! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is CutCopyMode ("marching ants frame") active? In this case, Excel tries to paste on insert. Use `Application.CutCopyMode=0` before the Insert statement to be sure.

Otherwise, it should work (works for me at least)...

Also, you can speed it up by inserting both rows at once:
`rangeCell.Resize(2,1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown`

Comment: Thanks man, that was it! Had no idea that was even a thing xD